# How to know the connection string in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to import data from text file to hive table using scoop. But I dont know the jdbc connection string to connect to hive. But do know the username and password. How can I find it from the terminal.

$ sqoop import \
*--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdb *
--username XXXX \
--table emp --table1

Comment: By default it is `jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000`

Comment: How to know if it is other than localhost and 10000? is it present in any files ?

Comment: [`hive-site.xml`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2)